# How to keep selected tab active in javascript tabs after postback event in asp.net

Tags: javascript

Hello I want to keep selected tab active on page refresh, How I will achieve this. I have found solution for bootstrap table but not for java Script tabs. How to do that ?

HTML

```
    <h2>Tabs</h2>
    <p>Click on the x button in the top right corner to close the current tab:</p>
    
   <div class="map-tab" id="mytab">
                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="selectedTab" runat="server" Value="0" />
                                                    <a class="map-tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab1')" id="defaultOpen" value="0" runat="server">Kharif</a>
                                                    <a class="map-tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab2')" id="defaultOpen1" value="1" runat="server">Rabi</a>
                                                </div>
    
    <div id="Tab1" class="map-tabcontent">
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="Tab2" class="map-tabcontent">
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
    </div>
```

Js

```
<script>
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
        var i, mtabcontent, tablinks;
        mtabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("map-tabcontent");
        $("#<%=selectedTab.ClientID%>").val(event.currentTarget.attributes.value.value);

           for (i = 0; i < mtabcontent.length; i++) {
            mtabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        mtablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("map-tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < mtablinks.length; i++) {
            mtablinks[i].className = mtablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
</script>
```

Jquery function

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tab = document.getElementById('<%= selectedTab.ClientID%>').value;
            $('#mytab a[href="' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: How do you generate the page? Server-side?  Does the server-side know which tab to select?  Add the relevant class directly to the HTML as you build the page.

Comment: @freedomn-m No It's not generating server side